# Multiply database value with user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, database, function, math

I have a form that echo's out data from a DB, including three sets of dollar amounts. I also have a number input box for the user to enter the amount of years. I am trying to multiply the dollar amounts by the amount of years the user puts in. I have tried creating functions but can't get it to work. Any suggestions? Thanks

User input with onchange event, and list of echo'd out dollar amounts from db. (getMoneyValue is a function to format the dollars).

```
<dt>Number of Prorated Years:</dt>
            <dd><input type="number" class='form-control' id="proratedYears" name="proratedYears" onchange="multiplyCosts()" min="0" max="20"/></dd>
            <dl>
              <dt>Direct Costs</dt>
              <dd><?php echo $functions->getMoneyValue($recordInfo['directCost']);?></dd>
              <dt>Indirect Costs</dt>
              <dd><?php echo $functions->getMoneyValue($recordInfo['indirectCost']);?></dd>
              <dt>Total Cost</dt>
              <dd><?php echo $functions->getMoneyValue($recordInfo['totalCost']);?></dd>
            </dl>
```

This is as far as I have gotten on the onchange function. I am really lost on how to procced.

```
 function multiplyCosts() {
  var proYears = document.getElementById("proratedYears").value;
  var adjDirectMulti = ($recordInfo['directCost']);

  var multiTotal = proYears * adjDirectMulti;

}
```

Comment: There are multiple such `<dl>` tags or only one which you have posted ?

Comment: There is one other set of <dl> tags, but they would not be affected by the user input.

Comment: where do you need to put `multiTotal` total ?  Also you can use jquery here ?

Comment: Honestly, at this point I can put multiTotal anywhere on the form as long as it gives the result. Yes, I can us jquery.

Comment: I can create readonly textboxes for multiTotal, if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can give `id`to `<dd>` tag  to fetch `directCost` value and then use `.value` to set value of textbox to show total .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function multiplyCosts() {
  var proYears = document.getElementById("proratedYears").value;
  var adjDirectMulti = document.getElementById("directCost").textContent;//get value

  var multiTotal = proYears * adjDirectMulti;
console.log(multiTotal)
document.getElementById("totals").value = multiTotal //set value of textbox
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<dt>Number of Prorated Years:</dt>
<dd><input type="number" class='form-control' id="proratedYears" name="proratedYears" onchange="multiplyCosts()" min="0" max="20" /></dd>
<dl>
  <dt>Direct Costs</dt>
  <!--give id-->
  <dd id="directCost">
   121
  </dd>
  <dt>Indirect Costs</dt>
  <dd>
   25
  </dd>
  <dt>Total Cost</dt>
  <dd>
    145
  </dd>
</dl>
<!--give id-->
<input type="text" readonly id="totals">
```